# Error trying to publish .net maui app iOS version using Visual Studio on Windows

Tags: c#, ios, maui, visual-studio-2022

I'm developing an application in .Net Maui for iOS and Android. For Android all is good but I have some problems with iOS. I linked windows pc with a VMWare machine where I put on macOSVentura with xcode and visual studio installed. The debug mode works correctly.

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4397) for publish the app but when I try to publish it I got this error:

```
Error   MSB4018 The "ReadItemsFromFile" task failed unexpectedly.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingException: A timeout occurred on client build258046576mtq28 while executing a post for topic xma/agents ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__21`2.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 188
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__21`2.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 239
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingRunnerPro.<ExecuteWithRetryAsync>d__12`1.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\MessagingRunnerPro.cs:line 55
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

(the error was much longer)

If I try to execute the command in PowerShell as in the guide I got this error

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\16.2.2054\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(1738,3): error : Could not find Microsoft.iOS in /Users/username/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/packs/
Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.2.2054/. [C:\Users\localusername\source\repos\appname\appname\appname.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-ios]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\16.2.2054\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(1738,3): error :          
[C:\Users\localusername\source\repos\appname\appname\appname.csproj::T
argetFramework=net7.0-ios]
```

I also tried to follow the [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-app-store?tabs=vs) :
[but I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdnAD.jpg)

I guess I created correctly every Application documents as in both tutorial, I also downloaded this file 'Worldwide Developer Relations - G3 (Expiring 02/20/2030 00:00:00 UTC)' in my macOS.

Any solution?

Comment: Certificates can be used for many purposes.  The link you provided is a certificate used during publishing your application.  The exception says : D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\MessagingRunnerPro.cs:line 55 which looks like TLS (ssl is really TLS) failed during a connection.  So error is when you are trying to connect between client and server.  One reason could be the TLS certificate isn't loaded on both client and server.  What version of IOS?  The TLS certificate has an encryption mode that has to be supported by both client and server.

Comment: Target iOS version 11. I should have installed the certificate in both pc.

Comment: The publish certificate is not the same as the TLS certificate.  But can be used for both.  See link in Blue Box : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-app-store?tabs=vs#create-a-distribution-certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error. Try to keep attention on the info.plist file if you added something wrong (for example on the map) fix the request or delete it if you don't need it.
Then try again.
If it still doesn't work, try passing the project into the VM and publishing it from the visual studio inside the mac.
This worked for me.